# How to get full html with react testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm running a react test and running:

```
expect(screen.queryByTestId(id)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

My test is failing, and the stack trace returns the html which is very helpful.

However, it crops the html, so for any reasonable website, it is only really helpful in the headers. Is there a way for the error message not to crop the HTML?

Basically, it shows the same as `screen.debug` but I would like to show the same as `screen.debug(undefined, Infinity);`

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you out, if it doesnt work please let me know, in order to showcase HTML output in your Jest error message which you mention that it is failing, why dont you take the benefit of the toHaveHTML matcher from the @testing-library/jest-dom package.

In order to do this you need to first, install this package:

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom
```

Secondly, you have to import **toHaveHTML** matcher in the test file by using the following code:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

After that, you can utilize the toHaveHTML matcher in your expect statement by using this code

```
expect(screen.queryByTestId(id)).not.toHaveHTML();
```

With this method i am hopefull it will show the HTML output in your Jest error message, in case if you still have issues please elaborate your problem in more detail, and i will try to help you out in this regard.

Comment: Is there a way to use the same assert? toBeInDocument is idiomatic, but toHaveHTML is not clear at all